# ODBC Finding the password an application uses to access the database

Tags: disassembly

I have a program which uses ODBC to access an accdb database. I can open it in access but it asks for a password.

[image]
The application accesses it through a DSN string. I have found the string using ODBC Data Source Administrator. However, I cant find the password! (even in the registry)

Is it possible to record the incoming connections to ODBC and snoop the password from the connection attempt? I have tried tracing, but I cant see it in the log.

Also would the program access the db using the connection string or does it decrypt the database first of all. I have tried using IDA to pull out the strings/ trace but cant see anything meaningful.

Is there a password cache location that I'm missing.

Comment: There are sw specialized in windows passwords. It a more easy.